# How do I display data from plist in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to show data from a plist file in a custom UITableViewCell.

Here is my rootViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"projects" ofType:@"plist"];
    projects = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        int n = indexPath.row;
        for (n=1; n<4; n = n+1) {

            NSDictionary *temp = [projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            projectCell.name.text = [temp valueForKey:@"name"];
        }
    }
    return projectCell;
}
```

The plist file i created only contains 4 dictionaries. And each one of them contains 2 strings. But I only want one of them to be in the cell. (I already created the UITableViewCell file named "ProjectCell".

I'm just starting, so my question might be really basic. But I spent so much time trying to figure it out.

Could anyone help me out?

EDIT: when i build and run, it always gives me a blank table

EDIT2: Interface of ProjectCell

```
@interface ProjectCell : UITableViewCell {

IBOutlet UILabel *name;
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *theCell;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *theCell;

@end
```

EDIT3 ProjectCell.m

```
@implementation ProjectCell

@synthesize name,theCell;

@end
```

Comment: Is `ProjectCell` a subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Did you setup the `datasource` and `delegate` of the table view appropriately?

Comment: Yes, i connected them the file's owner. I'm thinking the problem might be at my enumeration logic. Do you think I should use for (id .. in ..) instead? Or non is needed at all.

Comment: How did you design your `ProjectCell`? Is this via IB? And elsewhere you can check for the value returned by `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]`

Comment: check if the `ProjectCell` is being returned properly.

Comment: Please tell me where to put this line in. And yes, I designed the cell via IB. (fyi, i put NSLog in viewDidLoad and cellForRowAtIndexPath. Only ViewDidLoad was called.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off adjusting the XIB a bit.

- Click on the `UITableViewCell` object and change its class to 'ProjectCell' using the identity inspector.
- Now wire the `IBOutlet name` from this object to the existing label.
- Select the `File's Owner` and set it back to NSObject.

Now your `ProjectCell.h`,

```
@interface ProjectCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel *name;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@end
```

and your `ProjectCell.m`,

```
@implementation ProjectCell
@synthesize name;
@end
```

And the final changes will be in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProjectCell";

    ProjectCell *cell = (ProjectCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@”ProjectCell” 
                                                                     owner:nil 
                                                                   options:nil];

            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ProjectCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (ProjectCell *)currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    NSDictionary *temp = [projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.name.text = [temp valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still shows nothing in the table. I think it's because the cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called. What could cause this to happen?

Comment: In `-viewDidLoad:` of the `UITableViewController`, can you check the following values for `nil` – `self.tableView` `self.tableView.delegate` and `self.tableView.datasource`. Something is wrongly wired up for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right way to check it. But this is what i put into -viewDidLoad                                                if (self.tableView == nil) {
        NSLog(@"self.tableView is nil");
    }
    
    if (self.tableView.delegate == nil) {
        NSLog(@"self.tableView.delegate is nil");
    }
    
    if (self.tableView.dataSource == nil) {
        NSLog(@"self.tableView.dataSource is nil");
    }
                                                                       non of these logs came up in the console

Comment: Strange! Everything seems to be wired up right but the method isn't being called. Now can you post the `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods? Also, what is the `File Owner`'s class set to.

Comment: The file's owner's class is set to "RootViewController" (same as the name of the xib) Here's the methods u asked for                     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [projects count];
}

Comment: and the cellForRowAtIndexPath is the same as your answer. I can't post it in the comment because it's too long.

Comment: Everything seems correct. Do `[self.tableView reloadData];` after you have initialized the array in `-viewDidLoad:`. Make it the last line.

Comment: Has the array loaded properly? Is `[projects count]` returning 0?

Comment: Please tell me how to check the return of [projects count]. I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Replace the `[self.tableView reloadData];` that I suggested with `NSLog(@"%d", [projects count]);`.

Comment: Finally we know our problem. :) Check if `projects` is nil like you did earlier in `-viewDidLoad` and you need to retain the array returned. `projects = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] retain];`

Comment: Should've caught this long time back.

Comment: cool! The project is really nil. But the projects still return nil, even after i retained it. I think it might be the plist file. So if you want to look at it, here it is [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?18e96yxdmk6td2l)

Comment: sending a retain on nil doesn't do anything. The link seems to be broken.

Comment: Sorry about that, somehow i can't upload the plist. So i uploaded a screenshot instead [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?vuias8ngodbc9zv)

Comment: plist you have saved is a dictionary. They are by default created as dictionaries. You can change this by editing the source. Right click on the plist file and open as source. Now copy the code I pasted under EDIT into the plist and reopen it as a property list. This should do it.

Comment: The app crashed after i changed the plist file. Here's the the error : "** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x4b225f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theCell.'." The line " NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProjectCell" 
                                                                 owner:nil 
                                                               options:nil];" in cellForRowAtIndexPath is hi-lighted in green.

Comment: What is the name of the XIB file that you've created for your custom cell?

Comment: Which class is the file's owner in the XIB

Comment: The file's owner's class is "ProjectCell"

Comment: Can you post the interface of the `ProjectCell`?

Comment: Yes, I posted it in EDIT2 of my question

Comment: Strange. Can you send the xib file? zip it.

Comment: Here it is [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?eglr5mgsrzcmlb6). But, I didn't zip it, because i don't have a zipping software. I hope it's not a problem.

Comment: The table is still blank. I placed the NSLog in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and it was called 4 times.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out so much. I really appreciate it. You're probably the most generous (and patient) person on the internet =)

Comment: It has been an interesting effort. However I have edited my entire answer and posted some changes. Take a look.

Comment: I tried the updated version. I gave me this error. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x601f1f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theCell.' And the green hi-light is at the same place         (NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProjectCell" 
                                                                 owner:nil 
                                                               options:nil];) Thread 1 : Program receive signal "SIGABRT"

Comment: Are you referring to `theCell` property elsewhere? I removed it entirely from the above code. You should too.

Comment: Yes, i did. I just a searched the project, and there's no result.

Comment: Check the XIB again and right click on `File's owner` and disconnect any existing connections.

Comment: I deleted those connection (there were warning signs on them, so they were surely problems). The same error persists.

Comment: Do a `Product` > `Clean` and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating UITableViewCell objects you need to use your custom ProjectCell class.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProjectCell";

    ProjectCell *cell = (ProjectCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[ProjectCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *temp = [projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.name.text = [temp valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I did change it but the table still shows up blank. Any idea?

Comment: Please post the implementation of the ProjectCell class so we can see if the problem may be there.

Comment: I posted in EDIT3 of my question. There were some methods in there, but i commented them out, because they cause warnings. I just tried to uncomment them, it still shows a blank table.

Comment: Did you create the cell layout in IB? If so you need to load the cell in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

.M

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *mylist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name of your plist file" ofType:@"plist"];
    tabledata = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:mylist];
    NSLog(@"%@", tabledata);
    [super viewDidLoad];

   }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [tabledata count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if( cell == nil )
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell Creation");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    //Set Data For each Cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [[tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellSubtitle"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}



-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

}

@end
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface plistTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *tabledata;
}

@end
```